# Prove that there are no solutions to the modular equation 9x + 10 = 6y - 1 (mod 15)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Question: prove that for integers x and y there are no solutions to the modular equation
$$
9x + 10\equiv 6y - 1 \mod 15
$$

So my first thought was to assume that the congruence does have solutions, so 15 would divide the difference between the two equations. Meaning:
 $$
(9x + 10) - (6y - 1) = 15k \\
9x - 6y + 11 = 15k
$$
for some integer k. Then I notice that we have a lot of multiples of 3 here, so I rearrange it like this:
$$
11 = 15k - 9x + 6y \\
11 = 3(5k - 3x + 2y)
$$
This means 11 is an integer multiple of three. Clearly this is false, so we have arrived at a contradiction. Therefore there is no integer k such that $9x - 6y + 11 = 15k$, and thus the original modular equation has no solutions.

Is my logic valid? Is this the best way to prove this, or is there a more succinct and correct way? Thank you!

Comment: Can you solve the same equation modulo $3$? If you can solve it modulo fifteen, why should you be able to solve it modulo $3$?

Comment: It is well done. However, it is important to get accustomed quickly to "modulo" language, it will make arguments smoother.

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$ 9x + 10\equiv 6y - 1 \mod 15 $$
can be immediately taken mod $3$ since $3 \mid 15$. This yields
$$ 1 \equiv -1 \mod 3,$$
which is clearly false. So there are no such $x,y$.

Behind the scenes, this is precisely your answer. It just happens that one can get to it quite quickly.